# How to tune Apache Ignite failure detection threshold?

Tags: ignite

Obviously there's a trade-off between responsiveness and stability - what would be a good guideline here for tuning? In particular, I can imagine there's a big difference between non-virtualized, private virtualized and public virtualized environments in terms of what's achievable. The default of 10 seconds seems quite long to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 seconds is the smallest realistic value. In fact, it's very easy to have a GC or network glitch which takes more than 10 seconds and segments your node.

Please note that hitting failure detection timeout would very often mean downtime on the scale of many minutes, if more than one node is considered down. Given the severity, it makes total sense to wait for more than 10 seconds.

I would recommend 30 seconds for that value.

Comment: Note that the docs for tcp/ip discovery state “However, for stable low-latency networks, the parameter can be set to ~200 milliseconds in order to detect and react to​ failures more quickly.” This is what precipitated my question. So the docs should be updated with guidance then.

Comment: The fact that it *allows* such values, for extreme use cases such as compute-only grids, does not mean that you should 
"try that at home".